# Why dont google sample android-architecture todo-mvp project use robolectric to do unit test

Tags: android, unit-testing, robolectric, android-mvp

I have read the googlesamples/android-architecture todo-mvp code over and over again. I learned 2 things in the project, mvp and unit-testing. However, I'm wondering the developers don't use robolectric tools to test model-layer. The robolectric tools are faster and easier to use than the android instrumental test. To write mock and prod flavors looks a little boring. There has to be some reason. What is it?
[github](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture)